# How to get an option element's value by name

Tags: javascript, dom

First, I have absolutely no knowledge in JavaScript.

I try to return the value of an option from the HTML list below.

example:

- I have the var: `"NAME_1"`
- I need to return string : `"number:50640"`

How is this accomplished?

```html
<select class="form-control select-field ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched" id="upsell_product" name="upsell_product" ng-change="productSelected()" ng-options="product.id as product.name for product in products" ng-model="upsell.product_id">
  
  <option value="" class="" selected="selected">-- Select a Product --</option>
  
  <option label="NAME_1" value="number:50640">NAME_1</option>
  <option label="NAME_2" value="number:63732">NAME_2</option>
  <option label="NAME_3" value="number:32673">NAME_3</option>
  <option label="NAME_4" value="number:09723">NAME_4</option>
  <option label="NAME_5" value="number:23832">NAME_5</option>

</select>
```

Comment: What have  you tried?

Comment: In fact, I'm trying to automate something with FakeApp... and I need to pass some js because I've no other option for get this value... I've tried nothing because I don't know how to code js...

Comment: First step is to read JS tutorials and other instructional literature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how get value:

```
var selectVal=document.querySelector("select.select-field").value;
```

This is how bind when user selects:

```
document.querySelector("select.select-field").addEventListener("change",function(){

var selectVal=  this.value;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access the control using

```
var selectBox = document.getElementById('upsell_product');
```

and read the eslected options value

```
var selected = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
```